# Read a line in C and split it

Tags: c, fread, scanf

I got a problem trying to split 'str' in 2 int vars and 1 char var. Here is a code:

```
FILE *fp;
int i,j;
char str[8];
char valor;
if(!(fp = fopen("miniflota_g.dat","rb"))){
    printf("Error opening file.");
    getch();
    return;
}
while(fread(str,sizeof(str),1,fp) == 1){
    sscanf(str,"%d %d %c",i,j,valor);
    printf("%d %d %c",i,j,valor);
}
fclose(fp);
```

And this is an error:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. what doesn't work? 2. why do you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: 1. sscanf dosn't work. Fires an error when I'm trying to split the str. Something like it enters in infinite loop 2. Because I need to read a file in binary mode.

Comment: what error is "fired"?

Comment: also you might want to zero-terminate the string to make sscanf work.

Comment: Could You show a *.dat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sscanf() works only on standard C 0-terminated strings. fread() does not append a 0 to what it reads. If you want to read 8 bytes and use sscanf() you need to 0-terminate the data first. So your array needs to be at least 9 bytes big, so you can append a 0 to the data.

Also you need to pass the variable addresses to it, so it can write to them.

So it should look more like this:

```
FILE *fp;
int i,j;
char str[9] = { 0 };
char valor;
if(!(fp = fopen("miniflota_g.dat","rb"))){
    printf("Error opening file.");
    getch();
    return;
}
while(fread(str,sizeof(str)-1,1,fp) == 1){
    sscanf(str,"%d %d %c",&i,&j,&valor);
    printf("%d %d %c",i,j,valor);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You never null-terminate 'str' so the sscanf could read off the end.
2. You need to pass to sscanf the addresses of the output variables, not the values. (Eg. `&i` instead of `i`).
3. If you enable compiler warnings (-Wall with gcc), your compiler will warn you about the second point, at least.