# How to split tokens inside a buffer c?

Tags: c, buffer

I am using fread to read the entire source file into a buffer. As the file is in the stream or in the buffer, the file consists of bytes, and not strings or chars, right? So how do I split the bytes, in the buffer, so I may output the tokens into another file so it can be parsed?

Is this the right way to approach this, or is there a better way? I heard that reading the entire file is the way to go.

I have tried using a string and char approach and have gotten back weird symbols, so I ditched them and started searching for an answer to the bytes.

```
FILE  *file;
FILE  *file2;
char *buffer;
void lex();
void parse();

void parse()
{
    file2 = fopen("test1.txt", "w");
    printf("been through parse\n\n");
    fprintf(file2, "The file called test1.txt contains this text\n\n%s\n\n", buffer);
}

void lex()
{
    printf("been through lex \n\n", buffer);
    parse();
}

int main()
{
    long    numbytes;
    file = fopen("text.txt", "r");

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    numbytes = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char));
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, file);

    printf("The file called text.txt contains this text\n\n%s\n\n", buffer);
    lex(buffer);

    fclose(file);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is tangential to your main issue — strictly, somewhere along the line you should aim to close `file2` too.  The system _will_ do that for you as you exit, but it isn't good practice to let it do that; you should close it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about closing the second file.

Comment: Reading the whole file as shown is one way to do business.  You should check that `fread()` returns as much data as you expected.  You then need to know what the file _does_ contain so it can be parsed.  If it contains lines of textual data, you can split on the newline separators an get each line in turn.  If the file contains binary data, you must know how that data was written to be able to interpret it.

Comment: @Lordravenblack here is some tips for you might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418440/read-a-line-in-c-and-split-it or
[link](https://github.com/susheelkumardwivedi/questionanswer/blob/master/split_file_delimeter.c) <-- click here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string (in C) must be terminated with a `NUL` character (0). `fread` does not add anything to the data it reads, so if you are going to use `fread` in the fashion you do, you'll need to add the NUL yourself (which means you need to make sure you've allocated one extra byte to hold it.)

But, frankly, I don't think this is the optimal strategy. Fir one thing, it precludes taking input from stdin or a pipe or anything else which is not a regular file (because those aren't seekable).

Generally, you can read and tokenise a file one line at a time, using `fgets`, or even a character at a time,